# With call of ajax, grid row id losing

Tags: c#, ajax

I have a grid. First the grid row is filled with row id (ie."tr" id) but when a button clicked (.Net Ajax) page gets refreshed. Then grid row id will disappear. How can this issue be resolved. I mean i need to retain row id when grid gets refreshed through Ajax call.

More clarity with call of ajax, grid row is losing the id. I need to retain that value. Is any method for that? Please help me.

```
protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:ChangeRowColor(" + e.Row.ClientID + ")");
}
}
```

Above is the code, after refreshing with ajax method, its row id gets null. So, at runtime i'm getting js error like id is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that `e.Row.ClientID` is null or empty after the postback? Instead of passing the ID of the row, just pass the row itself using `this`:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:ChangeRowColor(this);");
```

By doing this, you no longer have to use `document.getElementById` either, since the element will be passed in as an argument:

**EDIT**: This is a quick & dirty solution, but you can use a global variable to keep track of the previously selected row.

```
var previousRow;

ChangeRowColor = function(row){
    if (previousRow){
        previousRow.style.background = 'white';
    }
    row.style.background = "red";
    previousRow = row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,its working ..but now i facing new problem that on next row click ,i want to trace previous event id.Please help me sir..

Comment: Are you saying that you want to keep track of the row that was previously clicked?

Comment: Yes. I am looking for that. here I am using a grid in which when i click i want to change the row color to a new color. later when I click next row, the prevous row should become as old color and the present row shopuld get new color and as on